# How to overcome logging the printk messages?

Tags: kernel

I have downloaded the current kernel source code later i changed the source code by putting simple printk message in the code then recompiled the code,but at present couldn't be able to view those printk message when looked for those printk message in /var/log/syslog or dmesg .Please give me the solution that will help me to debug  view the printk message whatever i put should get reflected in the syslog file.

Comment: It is impossible to resolve error without viewing your code(and place where you insert it).

Answer (score 0):

> give me the solution that will help me to debug view the printk
>   message whatever i put should get reflected in the syslog file.

Few things needs to be checked for viewing your printk

- Included during compilation (Check configuration) ??
- Whether the particular function is called ??
- What is the [log level of printk](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing) enabled ?